# Adding Spree to an Existing Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce, spree

I have a rails app that I've built that I would like to add an estore too.  My plan was to do it using spree. A few considerations:

- I already have a user model, and am using devise for authentication
- I want to be able to include related products on various point of the
  site (for example, if the user is in the 'cooking' section of the
  site, show 'cooking' related products.
- I am hosting it on heroku, and I'd like for the store to be at:
  http://store.myurl.com

Does anyone have a good jumping off point? I've never worked with spree before, and it seems that most of the documentation is oriented towards people starting an app from scratch with spree. My google searching hasn't yielded too much that is useful.

Can anyone give me tips or point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may get stuck trying to stick two apps together, particularly if you have two authentication systems running.

I might consider getting Spree up and running first then adding the functionality from your existing app in bit by bit ensuring you 'extend' Spree so upgrades don't break your customisations.

And if you think your custom code may be useful to others you could make it into a Spree plugin.

Comment: i want to use the same authentication system, devise, if possible. Or is that something that is too difficult to do?

Comment: You are in luck, Spree uses devise now, details can be found at http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/release_notes_0_40_0#replacing-authlogicwith-devise